# Google Docs: How to find and display matching value on new sheet based on two criteria

Tags: google-sheets

I have created [a demo spreadsheet to help explain](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0ApRO9YjU_IjrdGxzbENncjRqZEVMQTJvRUpKcFRzTGc&usp=sharing).

(This is a small set of example data, the real set has more values [and the data may or may not be there from week to week])

I will have a static list of dimension values (in the example it is Source/Medium values) in the Report sheet. I want to compare the performance of a metric from week to week (Pageviews per Visit in the example)

Wanting to automate the getting of the appropriate values from Sheet1 and populate the Report sheet's corresponding empty cells with them

For example, cell B2 of the Report sheet would contain the value 6.05, and so on

Comment: Please _do not_ use URL shorteners here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure there is a way to display a matching value base on two criteria - wouldn't be the first time I was wrong though.

In the meantime, you could create three queries and query each week individually, then you could do a vlookup to get the data into your table. I created a [Google Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AqnBvM-d1dRpdEViU25zU25CTVRVODVJQkRSVEM5SEE#gid=2). You should be able to edit this, etc.

If you want to do more automation, for example, have the report run every Monday morning and have it sent to your email, you can use [my blog post](http://www.swellpath.com/2013/04/google-analytics-report-automation/) and scroll down to the Using Triggers and Classes to Automate your Google Analytics Spreadsheet Delivery section.

Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using vlookup and doing more queries as suggested :)

Comment: Please _do not_ use URL shorteners here.